# Store printf in a char array?

Tags: c

is there a way to take the result of a `printf in a char array`?

I need to set a string P: result

where `result` is an `int`

So if `result = 4;`

So I need a `char array` containing `"S: 4"`

Other methods are fine too, however I have my result in `printf`, so I wonder if I can just fetch it?

Comment: You can use sprintf, which writes into a char buffer? Make sure your buffer is big enough (expected length + 1 for the nul terminator)

Comment: Look up `sprintf`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html) (a safer alternative to `sprintf`). The only difference between `snprintf` and `printf` is that `snprintf` writes to a `char *` instead of directly to standard output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[128];
    int result = 4;

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "S: %d", result);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The result of `snprintf` should be checked to see if a larger buffer was required, or some other error occurred.

Comment: The buffer size was chosen to have sufficient room for the known inputs. The maximum length of the rendered string is 13 characters. Other error checking was omitted for brevity.

Comment: Sorry, my comment should have begun with "Generally speaking, ...".

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sprintf` to get the formatted string.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

Comment: It is too easy to cause buffer overrun with `sprintf`. `snprintf` is better, since buffer overrun is caused by the programmer telling the function the buffer is bigger than it actually is.

Comment: @jxh Using `snprintf()` like in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39495281/2410359) is not  much better than this answer.  It trades a bad problem (potential buffer overflow in the general case) with an _undetected_ wrong result.  Using `snprintf()` too often conveys a false sense of "safety" when the result of `snprintf()` is not checked.

Comment: @chux: The safety is real so long as the buffer size is correct. The wrong result is truncated output, which is not usually a showstopper when the output is intended for display. But checking success of functions that can fail is just SOP, and something code review and static code analysis tools should be able to find.

Comment: @jxh The safety is real for `sprintf()` too so long as the buffer size is correct. The "which is not usually a showstopper" is the false sense of safety of my comment. `char s[16], sprintf(s, sizeof s, "Target is %d %d", lat, lon); cmd(s);` Agree `snprintf()` with result checking should be SOP.

Comment: @chux: GNU provides `asprintf` for that.

Comment: @jxh  True, various good non-standard C library  alternatives exist to cope with weakness of `sprintf(), snprintf()`.  Source code for `asprintf()` is usually readily available.  Useful for systems that lack `asprintf()` should OP be on such a system or need to improve `asprintf()`.